# Send only key value when using find method on a json array in JS

Tags: javascript, typescript

I would get a value from JSON array, so I use the `find` method:

```
let actualElm = this.initialData.find(elm => {
  if (elm.identifiant == this.actualId) {
    return elm.country;
  }
});
```

The problem with `find` is that it's returning all of the object ( `elm` object ) I would only get `elm.country`.

How can I proceed ?

Comment: Can you provide your JSON data? Right now we would have to guess your data

Comment: Without JSON data how can we find. provide JSON data as well

Comment: Why don't you pipe another function and do whatever you want with that returned element? This way your code is clean and readable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simplify your [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) function and just call `.country` after :

```
let actualElm = this.initialData.find(elm => elm.identifiant == this.actualId).country;
```

If your `find()` can fail in your case, add a fail-safe `(... || {})`:

```
let actualElm = (this.initialData.find(elm => elm.identifiant == this.actualId) || {}).country;
```

Answer (score 3):

The `find` method scans the array and returns one of the elements of the array when the provided function returns a truthy value. In your example, when the `if` condition is true, it will select that element and return it.

You can do like this:

```
let elm = this.initialData.find(elm => elm.identifiant == this.actualId);
let actualElm = (elm || {}).country;
```

Notice find can return `undefined` if the element was not found, so I had to check it exists.

Answer (score 2):

Find takes a function that return boolean, which determines if current element match given condition. If that's true, returns whole element.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

You can use foreach to achive what you want

Answer (score 2):

Those are the semantics of [`Array.prototype.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find). It will return the first element for which the callback function evaluates to a [*truthy*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) value. In your example, the callback method returns the `country` property, which is a *truthy* value, but that doesn't change the fact that `find()` will still return you the complete object.

Provided that you're guaranteed to find a result, you could just do the following:

```
let country = this.initialData.find(e => e.identifiant == this.actualId).country;
```